# Unable to cast object of type System.Data.DataRowView to type System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

My code looks like this, there is datarowview here..i am using a ListView control in XAML

```
private void btnApply_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> prtArray = new List<string>(); 

    foreach(ListViewItem lst in lstPrt.Items) // <--throws error here
    {
        if(lst.IsSelected == true)
        {
            prtArray.Add(lst.Content.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried switch `lstPrt.Items` to just `lstPrt`, the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: `lstPrt.Items` does not contain `ListViewItem`'s. It is seemingly populated from a DataTable ... you need to handle DataRowView instances in your for loop.

Comment: Hi, yes, i have filled the listview using a datatable. I was under the impression it will automatically convert each row into ListViewItems to fill the ListView. @rene

Comment: It doesn't need to convert to ListViewItem  as DataTable and DataRowView implement the interfaces needed by the Binder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView.Items can be a list of anything you assign to it. It is likely the list of DataRowView objects. The ListView will wrap those objects in ListViewItem(s) for display. You can probably use the lstPrt.SelectedItems to get the list of DataRowView objects and iterate over those.

```
foreach(var item in lstPrt.SelectedItems)
{
    prtArray.Add(item.ToString());
}
```